# docker compose otel collector permission denied in retrieving configuration file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, open-telemetry

I have my file docker-compose.yml :

```
otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
      - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
      - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
      - "4317:4317"   # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - "4318:4318"   # OTLP http receiver
      - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
```

I see this error after execution of `docker compose up`:

> otel-collector  | Error: failed to get config: cannot resolve the
> configuration: cannot retrieve the configuration: unable to read the
> file file:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: open
> /etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: permission denied otel-collector  |
> 2022/01/09 11:15:47 collector server run finished with error: failed
> to get config: cannot resolve the configuration: cannot retrieve the
> configuration: unable to read the file
> file:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: open
> /etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: permission denied

How can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like lack of permissions to access the file.
To determine if that's the case, try changing the permissions of `./otel-collector-config.yaml` using `chmod 777 ./otel-collector-config.yaml`.

If that's the case, then just set them to something more suitable like `chmod 660 ./otel-collector-config.yaml` or `chmod 666 ./otel-collector-config.yaml` since you'll probably not need the execution permission.

Comment: Thanks @SashoNajdov, but I have just tried this approach without any result

Comment: Try to mount the folder, instead of the file. And try to do this in some folder other than `/etc`.

E.g.:
`- ./:/config`
and then change the command to: `command: ["--config=/config/otel-collector-config.yaml"]`

Keep in mind that this will mount the whole folder, so maybe a separate config folder with just the config file inside would be better.

So:

`- ./config:/config` where `./config` contains the config file.

Comment: Same with your approch @SashoNajdov "Error: failed to get config: cannot resolve the configuration: cannot retrieve the configuration: unable to read the file file:/custom_otel/otel-collector-config.yaml: open /custom_otel/otel-collector-config.yaml: permission denied"